# Is there a way to use functions from a "double require"

Tags: node.js, require

Sorry if the title is misleading or vague, I couldn't really think of a good way to describe what I'm trying to do.

Basically, I have my **index.js** file calling another file via a require, we'll say it's **js_functions.js**. 
**js_functions.js** is calling multiple files via require, and those individual files are all exporting functions correctly.

For sake of example, we'll say that the structure is **index.js** > **js_functions.js** > **add.js**.

Is there a way to  call a function from **add.js** in **index.js** without directly requiring the **add.js** in **index.js** (via **js_functions.js**)?

Comment: Please show the actual code you're asking about.  Questions about code here should contain the actual code.  Include the code directly in the question and format it appropriately as code.  We can help you more accurately and quicker when you include the code.

Comment: @jfriend00 In this case, the code currently in the files is irrelevant. This is not a question of how to fix my code, it's a question about if something can be done (and how). Unfortunately, there's nothing in my code that will aid anyone trying to answer my question.

Comment: That's what people think.  That makes your question a theoretical question that's harder to answer accurately.  Even if you just show us an example  of code that's trying to do what you do, we can understand your question a LOT easier than just reading words.  Please trust what we say in this regard.  I've answered over 11,000 questions here.  Lots of new folks think they should describe a generic problem when they start asking questions here and the actual problem is ALWAYS clearer if its illustrated with code.

Comment: I wrote an answer and tried to "guess" what you meant, but because there was no code example, I'm not sure I guessed correctly.  A small code example of what you're trying to do would have made it absolutely clear what you meant in the question.

Comment: @jfriend00 I would normally agree with you, but in this case my code is quite literally blank except for the exports, requires, and one function that just logs a message to the console. I appreciate your answer though, it did help me decide how I should move forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `index.js` wants to call a function from `add.js`, then you have two options:

1. `index.js` can `require('add.js')` directly and thus get the exported function from `add.js` to call.
2. `js_functions.js` can export the function from `add.js` so when you `require('js_functions.js')`, the function you want to call from `add.js` is available in the `js_functions.js` exports.

Generally, I avoid dual exporting as in option #2 and if I want a function from `add.js`, I just make the dependencies direct and clear `require('add.js')` so I can get access to that function.

If you're new to node.js module development, then it takes a little getting used to that you start every new module definition, but just adding all the `require` statements that you need to get access to the modules/functions you need.  But, this is how you do module development in node.js and it has all sorts of benefits (testability, resuability, sharability, clear dependencies with no implicit dependencies, etc...).  So, just get use to adding a little extra code at the start of each module to import the things you need.

> Is there a way to call a function from add.js in index.js without directly requiring the add.js in index.js (via js_functions.js)?

Only if `js_functions.js` exports the function from `add.js` that you want to call.  Just because `js_functions.js` has already done `require('add.js')` that does not provide access to the exports in `add.js` to any other code besides `js_functions.js`.

---

In the future, we can help you more accurately and quicker when you include the actual relevant code.  We tend to do a lot better with specific questions that contain specific code than theoretical questions that try to use words (and no code) to describe some problem.